# how can I list a certain user's activity in a branch

Tags: clearcase

Given a branch name  and a user id, I'd like to know what the guy have done to the files in the branch, how should I do ?

thanks.

Comment: If the cleartool command I mention in my answer does not give you the exact output  you are looking for, leave a comment on my answer: I will update it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a query with find:

```
cleartool find . -user aUsername -type f -branch "brtype(aBranchName)" -print
```

Note: Fisheye has:

- only alpha support for ClearCase (since July 2009, see [ticket 248](http://jira.atlassian.com/browse/FE-248))
- had no support before that (see [this thread](http://forums.atlassian.com/thread.jspa?messageID=257276577&#257276577))
- requires large system resources which makes it impracticable for large Vobs.

Answer (score 0):

Use a tool like [Fisheye](http://www.atlassian.com/software/fisheye/). It gives you all kinds of metrics on individual users.