# How to determine newly added elements into my private branch

Tags: clearcase

In a major development, I have added multiple files to the source control into my private branch. There were also existing files that was modified and checked into my private branch. Now as we are approaching to merge the changes to our project branch, I would like to validate all the elements I have newly added to my private branch, to ascertain if the locations are correct (ex, they should have been placed in another location and a symlink should have been added)

I listed all the elements in my private branch, but could not figure out, which of these elements were newly added.

Is there a reliable way to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a query finding all elements in a given branch since a certain date for a certain user:

```
cleartool find . -type f -branch "brtype(abranch)" -element "{created_since(10-Jan)}" -user aloginname -print
```

(this would search only files, as mentioned in "[how to find files in a given branch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2785791/how-to-find-files-in-a-given-branch/2786120#2786120)", and also in "[how can I list a certain user's activity in a branch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1372697/6309)")

The other approach is to create a dedicated (simple base ClearCase) view to display those elements, as in "[Get all versions from a specific time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10703227/get-all-versions-from-a-specific-time-clearcase-ucm/10703661#10703661)" or in "[how to find out all the activities happend in a branch in the last month?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1577980/6309)".

But generally, the first query is enough.